# Can't change default network interface windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, routing

See the screenshot below...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dt4FL.jpg

I have a virtual adapter and for some reason windows seems to be default to this one (192.168.1.5 in the route print) when i want it to use the real network card by default. The virtual interface had like a 20 something metric when it was automatic but i manually changed to 500, but as you can see the metric for the interface i want windows to use (192.168.1.43) doesn't seem to change... i'm not sure if this matters but i also noticed it stays on the top of the list as well. I'm guessing the "best" way to check which network connection windows is using is just by looking at which metric is the highest?

Answer (score 0):

`route print` sorts all the routes by the IP.  Your "default gateway" is actually the interface with the lowest metric.  Unfortunately, Windows with it's attempt at being intelligent will use interfaces with a higher metric if it believes (read that as "undocumented reasons") there is a problem with the gateway with the lower metric.

In my experience... it is better to simply specify 1 default gateway, and add static routes for the things on the other interface if needed.  You can leave the "gateway" blank on the virtual interface.

Comment: So is there a way to just force windows to use the real interface? The virtual interface is set to dhcp and i'm trying to set up ip forwarding on a linux vm, so for the vm the default gateway is my actual router.